# Backbone.js Backbonetutorials.com unable to console.log serializeObject

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, web-applications, underscore.js, backbone-events

I have been going through Thomas Davis's https://github.com/thomasdavis/backbonetutorials/tree/gh-pages/videos/beginner

His video can be found here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZSjvWtUxYk

Between 31-44 minutes he is explaining how to post and push to the server. He walks through different steps to test that the java/backbone code is working using alert and console.log.

I have spent a while trying to figure out what I have mistaken in my code that will not perform a alert or a console.log

I had re-written the code up to this point twice now and have been able to create console.log's from previous points in the video. However, now I am stuck and unable to finish this tut.

Here is console.log being used to test code (35 min)

```
var EditUser = Backbone.View.extend ({
    el: '.page',
    render: function () {
        var template = _.template($('#edit-user-template').html(), {});
        this.$el.html(template);
    },
    events: {
        'submit .edit-user-form': 'saveUser'
    },
    saveUser: function (ev) {
        var userDetails = $(ev.currentTarget).serializeObject();
        var user = new User();
        user.save(userDetails, {
            success: function (user) {
                console.log(userDetails);
            }
        })
        return false;
    }
});
var editUser = new EditUser();
```

Here is the code that we are using (44 min):

```
var EditUser = Backbone.View.extend ({
    el: '.page',
    render: function () {
        var template = _.template($('#edit-user-template').html(), {});
        this.$el.html(template);
    },
    events: {
        'submit .edit-user-form': 'saveUser'
    },
    saveUser: function (ev) {
        var userDetails = $(ev.currentTarget).serializeObject();
        var user = new User();
        user.save(userDetails, {
            success: function (user) {
                router.navigate('', {trigger: true});
            }
        })
        return false;
    }
});
var editUser = new EditUser();
```

His code that is in the gitHub is finalized and has some variation then what is in the video. However, I think my issue is just in the .js code that I have created.

My full code can be found here:
https://github.com/Gregory-Phillips/backbonetutorials/blob/gh-pages/videoIndex

Any feedback will be helpful
And props to Thomas for spending some time creating this walk-through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two errors in your code.

First, Here's what you are really using :

```
saveUser: function (ev) {
   var userDetails = $(ev.currentTarget).serializeObject();
   var user = new User();
   user.save(userDetails, {
        success: function (user) {
            success: function (user) { // you must delete this line
                router.navigate('', {trigger: true});
        }
    })
    return false;
}
```

The second error is in your template :

```
<script type="text/template" id="edit-user-template">
    <form class="edit-user-form">
        <legend>Create User</legend>
        <label>First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" />
        <label>Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" />
        <label>Age</label>
            <input type="text" name="age" />
    </form> <!-- // remove this line -->
    <hr />
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Create</button>
    // </form> : add it here
</script>
```

Comment: So thanks for reviewing my code to you both @mu is too short and Rida BENHAMMANE. I had been staring at the code for too long and needed a second pair of eyes.<br /> Simple mistakes I suppose.<br /> I was wondering why I could not see anything going on using Dev Tools, no network activity or anything. It help to put the closing tag after the dang button. And the duplication in the .js came from editing out the console.log that I had in a previous file.<br />Thanks for such a fast answer to you both. I'm sure I'll be back around soon.